# ggplot specify longitude/latitude axis breaks

Tags: r

I am using the following code to create a map of one 'trial_area' from a shapefile and overlaying a coastline and 'prod_areas' from a second shapefile. I'm then using the coord_sf to zoom the map to the st_bbox of the trial_area polygon. However for some areas (see the example below) the axis tick text labels end up overlapping, is there a way that i can specify the axis tick mark intervals to avoid this (e.g. .1 for latitude and .5 for longitude)?

```
poly <- trial_areas %>% 
filter(Id==5) 
ext <- st_bbox(poly)

plot_SoundOfSleat <- ggplot() +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'light blue'),element_line()) +
geom_sf(data=poly)+
geom_sf(data=prod_areas,fill=mycol) +
geom_sf(data = Scot, aes(),
        fill = "lightgreen",col="darkgreen") +
coord_sf(xlim = c(ext[1], ext[3]), ylim = c(ext[2], ext[4]))  +
ggtitle("Sound of Sleat Trial Area 5") +
geom_sf_text(aes(label = Producti_1), data=prod_areas,size=3,hjust=0, vjust=0) +
labs(x = "Longitude", y= "Latitude")

plot_SoundOfSleat
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`geom_sf()` should work seamlessly with `ggplot2::scale_*_continuous()`, where you can use the `breaks =` argument.  Be careful with west longitudes, as they're negative numbers in the data but positive in the labels.

I've included some examples below:

```
library(sf)

# sample data
nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# No edits to graticules
nc_1 <- ggplot(nc) + 
          geom_sf() +
          ggtitle('original')

nc_2 <- ggplot(nc) +
          geom_sf() + 
          scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(34, 35, 36)) + 
          scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-84, -76, by = 1)) +
          ggtitle('fewer lat, more lon')

nc_3 <- ggplot(nc) +
          geom_sf(data = st_graticule(nc, 
                                      lat = seq(34, 36, by = 1),
                                      lon = seq(-84, -76, by = 4)), 
                  color = 'orange') +
          geom_sf() +
          coord_sf(datum = NA) +
          ggtitle('using st_graticule')

# using cowplot to output single image, rather than 3
cowplot::plot_grid(nc_1, nc_2, nc_3, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

You should be able to use the output from st_bbox to automate a sensible number of graticules (grid lines) if necessary.